# Splitting up a string C#

Tags: c#

So, here is what I am trying to accomplish.

I have a string from textBox1.Text
ipaddress: 192.168.1.1
hostname: this.that.com
pingtime: 52ms

I am trying to search each line for the keyword, ie "ipaddress" then show what comes AFTER the space.  SO the logic goes

search textBox1.Text for "ipaddress"
find next space and display the rest of the line
save what was found as "foundipaddress"

Sorry, I'm just not good enough with C# just yet to even attempt this to write what I have.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void Main()
{
    string data = "ipaddress: 192.168.1.1 hostname: this.that.com pingtime: 52ms";
    string[] parsed = data.Split(new string[] {"ipaddress: "},StringSplitOptions.None);
    Console.WriteLine(parsed[1]);
    string[] parsed2 = parsed[1].Split(' ');
    Console.WriteLine("ip " + parsed2[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("host name: " + parsed2[2]);
    Console.WriteLine("pingtime: " + parsed2[4]);

}
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.1 hostname: this.that.com pingtime: 52ms
ip 192.168.1.1
host name: this.that.com
pingtime: 52ms
```

see it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S0J0Bd

Comment: Totally something I can work with but what if they are all on individual lines?  I don't want to show everything that comes after, just the IP address in the case if your example.

Comment: just split it again and go through the values..see edit.

Comment: Nevermind!  What you had actually worked exactly like it  was supposed to :-) Because each line is already split in the text box it auto-showed just to the end of the line.  Thanks!